# Extract data from a database if a specific value in is followed by a another specific value

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a database in MySQL where one of the columns consists of different types of events and I want to extract specific data to python. For example:

Database:

```
ID  Event  A
 1    1   jdf
 1    2   kfl
 1    3   sdf
 2    2   asd
 2    1   sdf
 2    4   asf
 2    2   asas
 2    3   aas
```

What I am looking for is to take the events equal to 1 if the next event is 2 and create a new table.

Output:

```
 ID  Event  A
 1    1   jdf
 1    2   kfl
 2    1   sdf
 2    2   asas
```

Comment: So are you looking for a pandas solution?

Comment: Luckily, all '1' events are succeeded by '2' events.

Comment: @yatu Yes,  I would prefer. But I don't mind if there is an alternative.

Comment: Also, your data set has no (apparent) PRIMARY KEY, rendering this problem essentially insoluble,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `shift`

```
ones = df.Event.eq(1)
twos = df.Event.eq(2)
ones_then_twos = ones & twos.shift(-1)

mask = ones_then_twos | ones_then_twos.shift()

df[mask]

   ID  Event     A
0   1      1   jdf
1   1      2   kfl
4   2      1   sdf
5   2      2  asas
```

---

`ones_then_twos` shifts the `twos` boolean series backwards by one to ensure that we have a two that follows a one.

```
ones_then_twos

0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
Name: Event, dtype: bool
```

But this only gets the ones that are followed by twos.  We also want the twos that are preceded by ones.  But these just come right after so we shift forward the same mask and use "or" to combine them:

```
ones_then_twos | ones_then_twos.shift()

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
Name: Event, dtype: bool
```

This is the mask we use and you can see that it is `True` for both the ones and twos where twos come on the heels of ones.

Comment: Is there a way to use this if I have a third event, but this event to be the same with the second? For example take the event 1 if the next two events are 2.